# Disable auto convert bg while dragging rendered picture from browser to photoshop

Tags: render, photoshop, bmp

How can I disable the auto convert black background while I drag a rendered picture from browser to photoshop?

I guess it happens because when I drag it saves in my pc as bmp and then copy it to the photoshop..

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Save (or drag) the image from your browser to your desktop first, and then drag it into photoshop. Transparency will be respected.